What is the fastest solution to remove lines from a text file?
In my project, I need to develop a program in Python to insert a UUID in a device. There will be 1.000 devices produced per day, the UUIDs need to be inserted into each device, and only once. I have a large input file (100.000 lines) containing all the available UUIDs, as follows:
str[32]
str[32]
...
str[32]
str[32]

Example:
deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
coolcafebabecoolcafebabecoolcafecoolcafe
...
deadbeefdeadbeefcoolcafebabecoolcafebabe
coolcafebabecoolcafebabedeadbeefdeadbeef

My program will be executed and closed every day. I need to make sure I won't use the same UUID twice.
I was thinking of two solutions:

Delete the line of the UUID in the input file once I have used it. Then, when I need a UUID, I only have to read the first line.

Change the format of the input file by adding a byte on each line, that is equal to 0 when the UUID is free, and set it to 1 when it has been used. When my program is first executed, I read the file to get the index of the first 0, then I can keep track of the index and set the byte to 1 each time I consume one UUID. For example :
deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef;1
coolcafebabecoolcafebabecoolcafecoolcafe;1
...
deadbeefdeadbeefcoolcafebabecoolcafebabe;0
coolcafebabecoolcafebabedeadbeefdeadbeef;0



It seems both solution imply having to rewrite the whole content of the file, am I right? Is there a better solution?

How about using two files. One file contains all the uids, the other file contains a line number. When you need a new uid, get the line number from file 2, read that line of file 1, and increment the line number.

Unless storage is (for some reason) a very pertinent problem...in which case you could perhaps consider consuming lines from the end and deleting them as you go? (I'm not sure whether this would actually be more efficient.)

False.  SO has guidelines.

You could perhaps use a Queue and some multithreading… And the ‘two files’ idea is a good one.

Here: Here's how to remove used UUID to solve your issue:
import os

def next_uuid(in_file, used_file):
    used = set()
    if os.path.exists(used_file):
        with open(used_file) as f:
            used = set(l.strip() for l in f)
    
    with open(in_file) as f:
        for l in f:
            u = l.strip()
            if u not in used:
                with open(used_file, 'a') as uf:
                    uf.write(f"{u}\n")
                return u
    
    raise Exception("No more UUIDs")

in_file = 'uuids.txt'
used_file = 'used.txt'

next_u = next_uuid(in_file, used_file)
print(f"Next UUID: {next_u}")

This script grabs the next available UUID from a file. It keeps track of used UUIDs in a separate file to avoid duplicates.
Basically, it works like this:

Read all the used UUIDs into memory
Go through the main UUID file
When it finds a UUID that hasn't been used, it:

Marks it as used
Returns it


If all UUIDs are used up, it throws an error

The script is pretty quick because it only reads what it needs and just adds to the 'used' file instead of rewriting everything. It should work fine for your daily prod.

Using a database like SQLite could be your best bet. Databases are designed to handle queries efficiently and are scalable.

Just like you suggested yourself, populate the database with each UUID and mark if they have been used or not. You can then query a single unused UUID from your database (something like this: SELECT uuid FROM database WHERE used = 0 LIMIT 1). Mark the UUID as used in the database when necessary.

Using text files for 100k entries is not something that I would recommend.

Note also that sqlite3 is built into Python's standard library - nothing needs installing https://pymotw.com/3/sqlite3/index.html

I think your main goal is "I need to develop a program in Python to insert a UUID in a device". Why not just use a UUID library? I'd use version 7, because it embeds the date and makes it sortable.
Why are you reading a file with precalculated UUIDs?
If you have to use a file, I'd make a copy (for safety purposes) and remove each used line of the file being processed. You could also use a database (SQLite) with new and used UUIDs tables but I would need to understand your use case better. Feel free to ask follow up questions.

Maybe OP works for a device-maker that is issued with pre-assigned ids (like Ethernet/Bluetooth MAC addresses) and they have to use the ones they are given rather than randomly generating their own.

Yeah it just seems like a backwards way to do it. Generate, assign, and save to a database is most efficient.

instead of messing with the original file, why not create a separate file to keep track of used UUIDs? something like this:

read the first unused UUID from your big file
use it for your device
append it to a "used_uuids.txt" file

next time you run the program, just check if the UUID is in the "used_uuids.txt" before using it. this way, you're only ever appending to a file, which is way faster than rewriting a whole big file
def get_next_uuid():
    with open('all_uuids.txt', 'r') as all_file:
        with open('used_uuids.txt', 'a+') as used_file:
            used_file.seek(0)
            used_uuids = set(used_file.read().splitlines())
            for uuid in all_file:
                uuid = uuid.strip()
                if uuid not in used_uuids:
                    used_file.write(f"{uuid}\n")
                    return uuid
    return None


No, you wouldn't need to rewrite the whole file. You would only need to rewrite parts of the file by opening in a+ mode and using seek(int), tell(int) and truncate(int) functions. You might not exactly need tell(), but it pairs well with the other two functions. You'd use seek() to move the file cursor to the start of the last line, read its contents, and then truncate() to the start of the last line, thus removing the UUID you just read.
You would need uniform and predictable line lengths. Using uuids gives you this. They are a fixed size and can be encoded only in ASCII. So even in UTF-8 they will have a fixed byte-size/size-on-disk too.
See the docs for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek

I would increment the line number each time and read the next uuid from the file instead or rewriting it.
def read_nth_line(file_path, n):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
            if i == n:
                return line.strip()
    return None  # Line number exceeds file length

call this function with incremented line number,
file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt'
line_number = 5
result = read_nth_line(file_path, line_number)
print(result)

